# How to return this property value?

Tags: javascript

Using console.log(instance.element);
Returns all these values:
[image: IMG]

The problem is the values are inside the 0 group. I need to return clientWidth value because I want to compare it with another value that I have.

I tried this:
console.log(instance.element.clientWidth) and returns undefined which I believe it's because I'm not accessing correctly.

Using Google Chrome inspector right click, I can copy the property path which gives me this: [""0""].clientWidth

I tried then: console.log(instance.element.[""0""].clientWidth)
But my Javascript editor throws me error on that sentence.

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you getting `instance.element` ?

Comment: I'm getting that from my element. My editor gives me that function to access to element properties. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is an object and it is not array

if you want to access its element you can use

```
var dataarray = Array.from(instance.element)
```

and then you can access `dataarray [0]`

Comment: Thanks. How would you access to dataarray[0]? using: console.log(dataaraay[0].clientWidth); ?